# Monomorphisms, unclear basic property, Functor

Tags: category-theory, morphism, monomorphisms

Suppose that for morphisms in a category it holds that
$f\circ u=v\circ f'$ and $g\circ u=v\circ g'$ and that for a functor
$F$, $Fv$ is a monomorphism. Suppose that $Ff'$ and $Fg'$ are distinct.
**WHY** it follows that $Ff$ and $Fg$ are **distinct**?

Comment: It doesn't. You are probably missing some assumptions or misstated what you want to ask.

Comment: Please see page 7 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2528.pdf). The end of the first paragraph.

Comment: And that includes many additional assumptions, most directly that $Ff'\neq Fg'$ and $F$ is faithful, plus additional assumptions on the categories.

Comment: OK. And assuming that, how this follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed is that $Ff’$ and $Fg’$ are also assumed distinct. Thus the mono property of $Fv$ implies $FfFu=FvFf’\neq FvFg’=FgFu$. Thus we must have $Ff\neq Fg$.